# How do I update OpenGL to 3.3 or higher on Linux Mint 18.1?

Tags: drivers, linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card, updates, opengl

I need OpenGL version 3.3 or higher to run Blender 2.8 and Meshroom properly.

It looks like I have 3.0 installed.

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
```

Is there any way to get OpenGL 3.3 installed without (a) upgrading the entire OS or (b) hosing the entire OS or (c) spending more time messing with it than it would take to reinstall a new OS?

I'm hoping there's a few commands that fix the issue wtihout causing any further problems.

I have a GTX 760 which Nvidia says supports Open GL up to 4.6. It's using the latest proprietary driver, nvidia-415. This is Linux Mint 18.1

**Update**: I'm confused now as glxinfo shows more than one version:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

It mentions 4.3 and 3.0, so I'm not sure which I'm using.

Comment: Blender 2.8 is beta, 2.79 is the current release.  Mint uses the Ubuntu repo for Blender; the version showing there is 2.69.  If you don't require features available only in the latest/beta version, you can save yourself headaches; let your package manager do its job handling dependencies without messing up other things that use them.  Meshroom is not plug-and-play on Mint (Ubuntu).  There are conflicts with native drivers you will need to deal with.  See https://github.com/alicevision/meshroom/releases/tag/v2018.1.0.  So OpenGL may not even be an issue, but other things are likely to be.